# A country that is not Canada

Tags: python, if-statement

For my code below in python.  How do I make it so if the country is not canada then just have it print the total_price with no tax?  Right now if I put USA it gives me the right price but it also gives me the price for the other provinces not mentioned.

```
country = raw_input('What country are you from? ').lower()
if country == 'canada':
    total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
    province = raw_input('What province are you from? ').lower()
elif country != 'canada':
    total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
if province == 'alberta':
    total_alberta = (total_price * .00005) + total_price
    print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_alberta)
if province == 'ontario' or province == 'new brunswick'\
or province == 'nova scotia':
    total_onn = (total_price * .0013) + total_price
    print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_onn)
if country == 'canada' and province != 'ontario' and province != 'new brunswick' and province != 'nova scotia' and province != 'alberta':
    total_else = ((total_price * .0006) + (total_price * .0005)) \
    + total_price
    print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_else)
else:
    print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_price)
```

Comment: FYI it is easier to say `if a in ('a', 'b', 'c')` than `if a == 'a' or a == 'b' or a == 'c'` etc

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem you're having? If you enter a country of `'USA'`, it should crash as soon as it gets to `if province...` because `province` isn't defined.

Comment: Better if you refactor your code a bit. It is a bit messy at the moment. You could group some provinces in a set, check membership of each `raw_input` in this set and then decide accordingly. Also, a set of all provinces should be defined, just in case someone puts something random. Then each set can be an item to a dictionary, whose keys are the country strings, should you need to extend this to other countries.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I'm new at this so I'm still learning.  This definitely helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean and pythonic version - your logic and ifs were poorly nested:

```
base_canada_tax = 0.13
provinces = {'alberta': 0.05, 'ontario': base_canada_tax, 'new brunswick': base_canada_tax, 'nova scotia': base_canada_tax}

country = raw_input('What country are you from? ').lower()
total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
if country == 'canada':
    province_in = raw_input('What province are you from? ').lower()
    total_price *=  1 + provinces.get(province_in, base_canada_tax)
print 'Your total price is {0}'.format(total_price)
```

Comment: IMHO this is best because you replaced all the ifs with a table

Comment: `if province in [province[0] for province in provinces]: total_price *= provinces[province]` - `else: total_price *= 1.0013` looks through the characters `'a'`, `'o'`, `'n'`, `'n'`, and `'a'`, so I don't think it'll work. You could replace those four lines with simply `total_price *= provinces.get(province, 1.0013)`. Also, I doubt that 0.13% is the correct tax rate.

Comment: You also have `alberta` twice, with different values.

Comment: Better, but the tax values are still very tiny (e.g. 1/200th of a penny on each dollar spent in Alberta).

Comment: LOL - I wish we could determine tax values programmatically, but those are in non-logical hands... Those are easily modifiable in the snippet, any other way would require a lot more work :-)

Comment: 99% chance it's just a power-of-10 error. Sales tax values like 5% or 13% make much more sense than 0.005% or 0.13%.

Comment: The tax rate was never part of the question, the logic was... I think our questioner got more than he bargained for...

Comment: They gave me .05% .13% etc. You're right though it does make more sense.  I appreciate all the feedback.  This is seriously the longest code I have ever written.  I just started and this definitely helps! :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful... do please select an answer though... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the first if :

```
country = raw_input('What country are you from? ').lower()
if country == 'canada':
    total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
    province = raw_input('What province are you from? ').lower()
    if province == 'alberta':
        total_alberta = (total_price * .00005) + total_price
        print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_alberta)
    elif province == 'ontario' or province == 'new brunswick'\
    or province == 'nova scotia':
        total_onn = (total_price * .0013) + total_price
        print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_onn)
    else:
        total_else = ((total_price * .0006) + (total_price * .0005)) \
        + total_price
        print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_else)
else:
    total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
    print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_price)
```

Comment: Okay this makes sense too. The first if is all canada then else is any other country...  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Nest the province logic into the `if country == "canada"`

```
country = raw_input('What country are you from? ').lower()
total_price = int(raw_input('What was your total price? '))
if country == 'canada':
    province = raw_input('What province are you from? ').lower()
    if province == 'alberta':
        total_price= (total_price * .00005) + total_price
    elif province in ['ontario', 'new brunswick', 'nova scotia']:
        total_price= (total_price * .0013) + total_price
print 'Your total price is ' + str(total_price)
```

Your boolean logic was also redundant in many cases and could be trimmed as I did above

Comment: You'll never get to the inner `else`, because `elif province != 'alberta'` always succeeds.

Comment: The first `if province == 'alberta'` catches that

Comment: Ha! Yeah, I just saw that. Sorry. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: A lot shorter and nicer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

put your `if province` statment inside the `if canada`   then put if the country is not Canada it will jump outside the whole if statment

```
if country =='canada':
    if province =='ontario':
    .....
else //the not canada statment
```

Comment: By the way, Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`.

Comment: I am more familiar with php and java, been a while since I even saw a python code

Answer (score 0):

This is based on @Incognos's answer, with the logic and numbers corrected:

```
provinces = {'alberta': 1.05, 'ontario': 1.13,
             'new brunswick': 1.13, 'nova scotia': 1.13} # excess alberta removed
base_canada_tax = 1.113 # 6% and 5% together as per question's (corrected) code
country = raw_input('What country are you from? ').lower()
total_price = float(raw_input('What was your total price? ')) # float
if country == 'canada':
    province = raw_input('What province are you from? ').lower()
    total_price *= provinces.get(province, base_canada_tax)
print 'Your total price is', total_price
```